# Relative File Opening with `open` When Directory Doesn't Exist

Tags: c, file, io, mingw

I am following the example code in *Hacking: The Art of Exploitation* and am running into an issue when running the following.

```
datafile = (char *) ec_malloc(20);
strcpy(datafile, "/tmp/notes");

fd = open(datafile, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
if (fd == -1)
    fatal("in main() while opening file");
```

The error message is:

`[!!] Fatal Error in main() while opening file: No such file or directory`

Where the bit before "No such file or directory" is created with the custom `fatal()` function.

Note that `/tmp/notes` does not exist in the program's location, but the `O_CREAT` flag should account for that (or so I thought). I've tried switching the `strcpy` segment to `".\\tmp\\notes"` but the result was the same. How can I create directories that don't already exist within the directory where the program is called?

I am using MinGW on Windows 10 and am compiling w/ `gcc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say `/tmp/notes` does not exist "in the program's location."  This implies that you are running the program in a directory FOO and expecting it to create a file like FOO/tmp/notes.  But what you actually asked for is /tmp/notes, which is an absolute path.  You probably want tmp/notes without the leading slash, but that too is a directory plus a file, and `open()` won't create the directory.  So either just use `notes` as the file to open in the current directory, or use `tmp/notes` and first call `mkdir("tmp")`.

Comment: Ah, so open won't create directories, only files? Changing the path to just "notes" worked perfectly. It seems that I misunderstood the O_CREAT flag. Thanks!